# How to display the summary of error message on top of the form in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator

i have Validation summary component as below:

The below component fetches the ngform but unable to subscribe to statuschanges/Valuechanges and display the summary of error message.

```
export class ValidationSummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form: NgForm;
  errors: string[] = [];

 constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.form instanceof NgForm === false) {
  throw new Error('You must supply the validation summary with an NgForm.');
}
this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
  this.resetErrorMessages();
  this.generateErrorMessages(this.form.control);
});
}

 resetErrorMessages() {
this.errors.length = 0;
}

generateErrorMessages(formGroup: FormGroup) {
Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(controlName => {
  const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
  console.log('control.......... ', control);
  const errors = control.errors;
  console.log('control.errors.......... ', control.errors);

  if (errors === null || errors.count === 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Handle the 'required' case
  if (errors.required) {
    this.errors.push(`${controlName} is required`);
  }
  // Handle 'minlength' case
  if (errors.minlength) {
    this.errors.push(`${controlName} minimum length is ${errors.minlength.requiredLength}.`);
  }
  // Handle custom messages.
  if (errors.message) {
    this.errors.push(`${controlName} ${errors.message}`);
  }
});
```

}
}

and  validation-summary.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="errors?.length > 0" class="validation-summary">
    <p>Please fix the following errors:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let error of errors">{{ error }}</li>
</ul>
```

dynamic-form.component.ts

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}
productFormGroup: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {

this.productFormGroup = this.formBuilder.array([]);
  this.ProductList.forEach(product => {
      this.productFormGroup.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        productId: [product.productId],
        displayName: [product.displayName],
        productName: [product.productName, Validators.required]
      }));
    });
```

}
 }

dynamic-form.component.html that uses the validation summary.

```
    <div id="mainWrapper">
      <app-validation-summary-component [form]="userForm"></app-validation-summary-component> 
    <form #userForm="ngForm">
<div [formGroup]="product" *ngFor="let product of 
         productFormGroup.controls>
      <label>{{product.get('displayName').value}}</label>
         <input  class="form-control" 
       name="product.get('displayName').value" 
        formControlName="productName" required/>
 </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
              [disabled]="!productFormGroup.valid">Submit </button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 30px" type="reset" 
       (click)="reset()"> Reset </button>
       </form>
</div>
```

Need to display the summary of error messages on top of the dynamic form component displaying the list of label names that is blank/Invalid.

Comment: you can make use something like flash in node,depending on platform you use on server side.

Comment: the resetErrorMessages() function should be `{this.errors=[]}`, you can not change the "length of an array", you shoul change the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are looping the formarray formgroup control is not proper inside validation-summary.component. Created stackblitz explains the solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mr49zh

Comment: Thanks  lot Suresh! this is exactly what i wanted .... but while displaying the error message it will pick the same name like "display name is required", instead it should pick the unique value and say angular is required. or React is required can u pls guide.

Comment: You should use 'display name'. upvote so helpful to others.

Comment: I did upvote , coz i have only 3 reputations :( , i actually want to display the Error msgs  like angular is required currently it is displaying display name is required for all the 3 fields if it has errors,  instead it should rectify the unique name for each fields and say angular is required or react is required ....

Comment: i think i found the solution with below piece of code....  if (formInnerControl && (_formControl.status === 'INVALID' || formInnerControl.errors) && formElement === 'displayName') {
             me.errors.push(formInnerControl.value + `is required`);
        } hope it is helpful to others....

Answer (score 0):

Here are the group of function that loops over every FromControls of FormGroup including nested FormControls in FormArray and Generating Validation Summary.

```
  getFormSummaryHtml(formGroup, fg_discription){
    let allErrors = this.getFormSummary(formGroup, '');
    let error_obj = this.setErrorFormat(allErrors, fg_discription)
    if (error_obj){
      let html = this.getHtmlFromObject(error_obj, '')   
  
      return html;
    }
  }

  getHtmlFromObject(error_obj, html) {
    if (error_obj.value) {
      for (let index = 0; index < error_obj.value.length; index++) {
        const element = error_obj.value[index];
        html += `<ul> <li>`;
        html += element.text;

        if (element.value) {
          html = this.getHtmlFromObject(element.value, html)
        }
        html += ` </li> </ul>`;
      }
    }
    else if (error_obj.length > 0) {
      html += `<ul>`;
      for (let index = 0; index < error_obj.length; index++) {
        const element = error_obj[index];
        html += element.text;
        if (element.value) {
          html = this.getHtmlFromObject(element.value, html)
        }
        else {
          // to Remove last appended text
          html = html.substring(0, html.length - element.text.length);
          html += `<li> ${element.text} </li>`
        }
      }
      html += `</ul>`;
    }
    else {
      html += error_obj.text;
    }
    return html
  }

  getFormSummary(formGroup, parentGroup) {
    let errors = []
    for (const key in formGroup) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(formGroup, key)) {
        const element = formGroup[key];
        if (element instanceof FormGroup) {
          parentGroup = parentGroup == '' ? key : parentGroup + '>' + key;
          let terror = this.getFormSummary(element.controls, parentGroup)
          errors = [...errors, ...terror]
        }
        if (element instanceof FormArray) {
          parentGroup = parentGroup == '' ? key : parentGroup + '>' + key;
          for (let index = 0; index < element.controls.length; index++) {
            let ele = element.controls[index];
            let terror = this.getFormSummary(ele["controls"], parentGroup)
            errors = [...errors, ...terror]            
          }
        }
        if (element instanceof FormControl && element.valid == false && element.errors && Object.keys(element.errors).length > 0) {
          for (const errorTypes in element.errors) {
            errors.push(parentGroup + '>' + key + ':' + errorTypes)
          }
        }
      }
    }    
    return errors;
  }

  setErrorFormat(errors,discription){
    let errorObj: { text: string, key: string, value: Array<any>};

    for (let index = 0; index < errors.length; index++) {
      let element = errors[index];
      let elements = element.split(':');
      let error_elements = elements[0].split('>')
      error_elements.forEach((ele,idx) => {
        if(errorObj == null){
          errorObj = { text: discription[ele], key: ele, value: null };
        }
        else if (idx > 0){
          let error_t_obj = this.getErrorElement(errorObj, ele);

          let error_ele_obj = this.getErrorElement(errorObj, error_elements[idx - 1]);
          if (error_ele_obj && (error_t_obj == null || error_t_obj.key != error_elements[idx])) {
            let obj = { text: discription[ele], key: ele, value: null };
            error_ele_obj.value = error_ele_obj.value && error_ele_obj.value.length > 0 ? error_ele_obj.value : new Array();
            error_ele_obj.value.push(obj)
          }
        }        
      });      
    }
    return errorObj;
  }

  getErrorElement(error,s_key){
    if (error.key == s_key) {
      return error;
    }
    else if (error.value && error.value.length > 0) {
      for (let index = 0; index < error.value.length; index++) {
        let ele = error.value[index];
        let objerror = this.getErrorElement(ele, s_key);
        if (objerror != null ){
          return objerror;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How to call this ?

```
getFormSummary(){
// This array contains FromControls name and Names of controls that user can understand
let fg_discription = {
  saleGroup: "Sales",
  sale_date: "Sale date",
  sale_type_id: "Sale type",
  deal_type_id: "Deal type",
  lender_id: "Lender",
  wholesaler_id: "Wholesaler",
  published_price: "Published price",
  pack: "Pack",
  allowance: "Allowance"
};
let html = this.getFormSummaryHtml(this.addSalesForm.controls, fg_discription)
return html;
}

validateFormOnSubmission() {
let form = this.addSalesForm.value;
let html = this.getFormSummary()
if (html == undefined) {
// Submit Form
    this.onSubmitAddSales();
}
else { // Show Html in POP message
  this.popMessage({ detail: "Following fields are  mandatory: ", data: { html }, key: "popup" })
}
```

}

Comment: try to display the errors in "more Angular way": not create a text with the .html else use `*ngFor` directly in the .html

Comment: If you want object and display it using ngFor then 
`let error_obj = this.setErrorFormat(allErrors, fg_discription)`
has error object .